# Ошибка в mysql mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Проблема с добавлением пользователей в бд
код ошибки - `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1` 
Половина добавилась а другая нет, не могу понять в чем проблема.
бд (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbQw9.png)

````
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="discord"
    )

    cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
    conn.autocommit = True
    
    
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}',{member.id})")
                
                print(row)
            else:
                print(row,"in none")
 
                pass
            
                
                
           
    
    print('BOT successfuly connected')
    #await bot.change_presence(activity=nextcord.Game(name="EventBot"))
    #print("Был запущен -", time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', Start_time))
    ```
````

Comment: Засетил пользователя с ником в котором присутствует  '  
SaintD'#3236
Возможна ли ошибка из-за него ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью регулярных выражений
`memb = re.sub(r'["\']', '',str(member))`